# How do I achieve the equivalent of using small caps in Arabic?

Tags: typography, composition, arabic

I have this letterhead title in Hebrew, English, and Arabic, in which I set the English to Small Caps (that is, the first letter is a big capital, the rest are small). Now, in Hebrew, the letters are generally squarish, so they're kind of like small caps already (although there's no equivalent of the large cap). In Arabic, however, many/most letters are at half-height (e.g. و and د), while other rise well above the x-height, e.g. ال which denotes a definite article. But ال is not like a big cap at all, and the rest of my text looks so low(ly) compared to the English small caps.

What do I do?

[image: Illustration of the letter-head]

Notes:

- Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLasb.jpg) of Arabic in boxed letter-forms. It's not what I would be looking for, but does illustrate how Arabic type is amenable to many (acceptable) kinds of stretching, shaping and manipulation.
- Suggestions such as "Do something entirely different than small caps" are not entirely irrelevant, but I would rather stick to my original whim.
- I can't just have the script in every language be set in a different style altogether, consistent only with the custom for titles in that language.

Comment: Khaled Hosny’s advice in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159736 is relevant here.

Comment: @Thérèse: Yes, that's half-true in Hebrew as well (bold is ok, slanting - faux pas). However, neither Nastaliq nor Naskh will do for me. Is there a specific kind of script (or specific font family) you would suggest, which would go well with English small caps?

Comment: I don’t see how one could say in the abstract.  Some small caps are smaller than others, and x-heights differ, not to mention the less measurable differences in type design.  What does your letterhead look like apart from this problem?  Does it include decorative rules?

Comment: Table 7.2 of the `Arabi` package user guide is useful for quick comparisons of the ascenders and descenders in some readily available fonts.

Comment: This has been suggested for migration to graphicdesign: it's not a TeX question,  it's a typography one. I'm minded to go with that: any objections?

Comment: @JosephWright: Are you sure you're not migrating me to some limbo where nobody will answer my question? I've never been there before... :-(

Comment: There is no caps in Arabic to have smallcaps. I’d usually suggest to go with the Arabic style that gives the comparable feeling to the reader, but for a unicameral script there is nothing even close to this since it is dealing with a completely non-existing issue. For headers I’d suggest Riqaa, but there is not that many authentic Riqaa fonts (only the one [here](http://sultanmaqtari.wordpress.com/ruqa/) AFAIK, couldn’t find an English page), it does not give smallcaps feeling but it gives “header” feeling.

Comment: @KhaledHosny That sounds like the start of a great answer - it'd be really interesting to see some examples of how different Arabic calligraphy styles can be applied to modern typographic use cases like this

Comment: @einpoklum IMHO, it would be more useful to add your example to the Question itself: just write: ADDITION and place the image with the explanation

Answer (score 8):

It's unfortunate that Khaled hasn't had a chance to respond here, but I'll give you my typographer response.

As a general principle, I would *strongly* recommend sticking with the typographic conventions of each culture. Distorting letterforms (or choosing unusual typefaces that don't convey the same sense of formality as small caps do in English) is definitely not acceptable in a letterhead.

Imposing the sensibilities of one culture upon a communication to a different one is very dangerous. A Chinese designer used only to Chinese letterforms might think (I'm making this up as an example -- I have no idea what a Chinese designer might actually think) that Comic Sans or Chiller conveys just the right sense of dignity in a bilingual funeral announcement.

This is very much like the problem of translating idioms from one language to another. What works beautifully in one language can be a disaster in another. I once had a Thai translator ask me about the term "Christ-like" in a piece of text. "I can't say that in Thai," she said. "It would be an insult!"

Stick with conventions that work in each culture. Don't mix them, and for safety verify with a native reader that you've not committed any inadvertent faux pas.

Comment: Even within the bounds of the typographic conventions of a language, there's still room to maneuver. Plus, Arabic is famous for amenability to all sort of [stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashida) and [twisting](http://www.arabiccalligraphy.com/mokhtar-gallery/), much more than other languages I know in fact

Comment: Sound advice. For example, to my (non-Arab) eye, a subtle [Kufi style Arabic](http://sweetfernstudio.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/calligraphy-styles.jpg) typeface looks like it'd fit alongside the other samples - ***BUT*** as Alan G advises check with actual native Arabs as this might have unintended cultural associations so you don't for example stumble into using the Arabic equivalent of blackletter.

Comment: @user568458: Do you think you could your comment into an answer? Perhaps with a suggestion of some specific Kufi font, or at least a link to several potential Kufi typefaces?

Comment: I think if I did it'd imply that I have enough relevant expertise to recommend Kufi style fonts as a good option - but I really don't, it might give off completely the wrong impression to Arabic eyes. It looks like we don't have many Arabic users here unfortunately: I'd suggest browsing Arabic calligraphy / typography styles and finding an arabic-focussed Q&A site to ask what people associate with those styles.

Comment: @einpoklum: Eskimos are famous for having lots of words for snow. Unfortunately that is a myth. It is unclear how fluent you are with Arabic, but the question itself implies you may not be highly proficient else an "Arabic Smallcaps" analog would be obvious to you. You should heed the warnings here. The best advice in light of all this is that you should adjust the visual weight of the English text so that it best matches the visual weight of the Hebrew and Arabic. This is, after all, the purpose of Smallcaps in English texts: to get the uppercase to fit within the surrounding context.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the advice here. _Do not_ try to fumble in the dark after fonts you do not know the context, the connotation to. If you do not have a native arabic designer around, then _alter the stuff you know_: alter the latin and the Cyrillic. Tread lightly; stick to the simple standards for that of which you know nothing.